# update wordpress field "DATE"

Tags: php, wordpress, date

So I have been trying to find a solution for this around 1 hour and I cant find the solution.

how do I update DATE with the update_post_meta() function?
I have ACF field which is jquery(date).
Ive tried

```
update_post_meta($post_id,'last_date',$arr[9]);
```

when `$arr[9]` is **22/09/2018**
like my Date format.

Comment: Why `jQuery` tagged?

Comment: Are you sure that the slug name of given ACF field is "last_date"? I think it is something different.

Comment: @ElvinHaci yep I checked it 10 times :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For update_post_meta function it doesn't matter which kind of value you have. It stores it as a string. So the problem can't be related to $arr[9]'s datetime format.

That's why there are only two options to check:

1. Write

   echo $post_id;

before update_post_meta() function and check if it displays correct ID.

2. Again, check your database wp_postmeta table and search for "last_date" field. May be it has some another prefix or postfix.

If to do these 2 steps, you will find the reason by 100%.

Answer (score 0):

try like this, I think your date format is not correct:

```
$date_stamp = strtotime($arr[9]);

$postdate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $date_stamp);

update_post_meta($post_id,'last_date',$postdate);
```

Comment: @AlexLeibovich this is the basic sturture:
update_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $prev_value );